# how can solve "undefined reference to `isascii'" when build OpenOCD in Win 7 (cygwin)

Tags: c, linux

i'm building OpenOCD on window 7 by Cygwin and got this message

```
openocd-0.7.0/jimtcl/jim.c:3009: undefined reference to `isascii'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:45: recipe for target 'jimsh.exe' failed
make[2]: *** [jimsh.exe] Error 1
```

maybe the library for 'isascii' doesn't exist in Cygwin
i followed these step for building:

http://www.tincantools.com/wiki/Compiling_OpenOCD_Win7

Comment: Insure you used `#include <ctype.h>` in the files that call `isascii()`.  You likely would have received warnings, had you not.

`isascii()` may be implemented as a macro.  If so, the function will not appear in a library.

Comment: in jimtcl/jim.c include ctype.h already...don't know how to fix this

Comment: `isascii()` is not a standard C function and may simple not exist in your environment.  As an alternative use `int MY_isascii(int c) { (c >= 0) && (c <= 127); }`.

Comment: is it fine if i follow this guide line: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235417.aspx
mean: i will revise isascii() into __isascii(). i've done and build go through, but don't know whether it's fine or not

Answer (score 2):

Same problem pops up with MinGW distribution. As appears in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/ctype.h.html, `isascii()` defined in `<ctype.h>` is an extension of ISO C standard. Therefore, not necessary available. As mentioned  above, the name without underscores is deprecated, starting from Visual C++ 2005 runtime library (installing an older MSVCRT runtime will not help).

So, using the `__isascii()` variant IS correct.

However, an older install of MinGW runtime with GCC 4.6.1 accepts `isascii()` without giving an error. That's because it is defined in `libmoldname.a` (`-lmoldname`) - one of the libs GCC uses for linking.
In recent versions of MinGW, `libmoldname.a` has been changed to remove some old functions, including `isascii()`. An object file `isascii.o` has been removed from this library.
These links relate to this removal:

sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/changeset/5807/trunk

sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/mingw-w64-public/thread/51751223.2020804@videolan.org/

http://marc.info/?l=mingw-patches&m=107980328623432

Unfortunately, `<ctype.h>` still defines `isascii()` without underscores. Thus, this error only appears at link stage.

In case, code change is not an option for whatsoever reason, use an older version of MinGW or Cygwin to build. To check if the distribution supports `isascii()` type:

```
objdump -t c:/mingw/lib/libmoldname.a | grep "isascii"
```

The output should be either empty (no support) or:

```
isascii.o:     file format pe-i386
[  0](sec -2)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl 103) (nx 1) 0x00000000 isascii.c
[  2](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty  20)(scl   2) (nx 1) 0x00000000 _isascii
```

Btw, there is no need to add `-lmoldname` to `$LDFLAGS`, GCC adds this lib automatically.